# trouble viewing h2 db used in grails project

Tags: grails, h2

I'm trying to have a look at the tables generated in h2 db used in Grails project, but something's amiss.

I connect to the browser console at http://127.0.1.1:8082/ but all that's there to browse is INFORMATION_SCHEMA and Users. How do I get tho the tables used/generated by the app?

Just started building out the app and only few domain classes are in place and I'm trying to get a feel for working h2. Prior to that I've been using PostgreSql in all projects so this is very unnerving for the moment.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Are you using the right JDBC URL when logging in?

The default in grails is `jdbc:h2:mem:devDB`.

When an non-existing URL is given, like `jdbc:h2:blabla`, an empty database is created, with the default `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` and `Users` as you described.

Make sure you connect to the URL where your grails application stores its tables. You can find the URL in `$GRAILS_PROJECT/config/DataSource.groovy`, after the `url` definition.

```
environments {
  development {
    dataSource {
      pooled = false
      logSql = false
      username = "sa"
      password = ""

      dialect = "com.hp.opr.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect"
      driverClassName = "org.h2.Driver"
      dbCreate = "create-drop"
      url = "jdbc:h2:mem:devDB;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;MVCC=TRUE"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: ... are you sure the dialect string doesn't have a typo in it?

Comment: Edited. I use a modified version of the H2Dialect in my project but it doesn't matter here anyway.

Comment: ... thanks for pointing me in the right direction :-) as well.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using 2.0 the web console is enabled by default in dev mode and can be enabled in other environments: http://grails.org/doc/2.0.0.M2/guide/conf.html#databaseConsole

If you're not using 2.0 yet you can install the http://grails.org/plugin/dbconsole plugin or follow the link to my blog post and set it up yourself if you want to customize the url (or if you're using Grails pre-1.3.6 since the plugin has an artificial version restriction to 1.3.6+)

Comment: Yes, I'm using 2.0. So again I can connect fine but I'm not seeing the tables created by the app. Is the h2 plugin set up properly in Config.groovy? (see question edit)

Comment: None of that applies to the H2 support in 2.0 - it just registers the web servlet so you can access it in a browser. The only customization options are whether it's enabled and what the url is.

Answer (score 0):

... so in datasource I changed the url to:  url = "jdbc:h2:rswDb" (removing the 'mem' part and changing the name of the db). Then 3 db files showed up in the root dir of the project.

Next, in db console set the jdbc url to: jdbc url:  jdbc:h2:~/work/web/rsw/rswDb

... and when I hit 'connect' all the tables were there!

Thanks again!